# Does being “considered armed” from the Deadlands version of Martial Arts Edge grant a +d4 too?

Tags: savage-worlds, unarmed-combat, deadlands-reloaded

I am thinking about playing a melee fighter in a Deadlands game.
I noticed the Martial arts edge in the core is slightly different than the Deadlands version.

Core reads:

> This character is highly trained in hand-to-hand fighting. He is never considered unarmed in combat and so is never subject to the Unarmed Defender rule (page 76). With a successful unarmed attack, he adds +d4 to his Strength roll (as if he were using a small weapon).

Deadlands reads:

> You’ve trained in martial arts or boxing, or learned to street fight really dirty. Your character’s body is a finely honed weapon, so even when your hero fights unarmed, he is considered armed. In addition, opponents in
>   melee combat never benefit from any gang up bonus against your hero.

In Deadlands when it says “considered armed”, is that the +d4? Or in this case is there a version where you ignore gang ups *or* get +d4 to punches?

Comment: Hi Jtet, and welcome to the site. Thanks for the question--well-posed questions are our bread and butter. WHen you get a chance go ahead and take the [tour], and happy gaming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The two Edges have different names, so their effects do not stack

In *Savage Worlds Deluxe*, the Edge is Martial **Artist**. In *Deadlands Reloaded*, the Edge is called Martial **Arts**.

Thus the only benefits you get for the Martial **Arts** Edge in *Deadlands Reloaded* is as follows:

> You’ve trained in martial arts or boxing, or learned to street fight really dirty. Your character’s body is a finely honed weapon, so even when your hero fights unarmed, he is considered armed. In addition, opponents in melee combat never benefit from any gang up bonus against your hero.

I'd like to point out that "opponents in melee combat never benefit from any gang up bonus against your hero" is extremely powerful, and no setting after *Deadlands Reloaded* has repeated this.

Why have two Edges with similar names? *Deadlands Reloaded* was created while *Savage Worlds: Explorers Edition* was the latest version of the core rules. That version lacked most of the Edges related to unarmed combat. The Martial Arts Edge was introduced in *Savage Worlds Deluxe*, which was released after *Deadlands Reloaded*.

### The SWD Martial *Artist* Edge is not permitted in *Deadlands Reloaded*

When *Savage Worlds Deluxe* was released, Pinnacle released "[Deadlands Deluxe-ified](https://www.peginc.com/store/deadlands-deluxe-ified-pdf/)", a PDF explaining how to incorporate the changes from the new core rules into *Deadlands Reloaded*. That document explicitly states that the Martial Artist Edge for *Savage Worlds Deluxe* is not available in *Deadlands Reloaded* (emphasis mine):

> The following Edges are not allowed in *Deadlands Reloaded*: Arcane Background (Psionics) or (Super Powers), **Martial Artist (or any Edge that lists it as a Requirement)**, Mentalist, Soul Drain, and Wizard. As usual, characters may only take one Arcane Background Edge.

### Regarding your other questions

> In Deadlands when it says “considered armed”, is that the +d4?

No, this refers to the Unarmed Defender rule (page 76 of *Savage Worlds Deluxe*). Since you are "considered armed", you are not subject to the effects of the Unarmed Defender rule.

> Or in this case is there a version where you ignore gang ups or get +d4 to punches?

There is no version of the Martial **Arts** Edge in *Deadlands Reloaded* that allows you to get an additional d4 for punches. The closest thing is the *Deadlands Reloaded* Edge Superior Kung-Fu: Eagle Claw Style, but that requires Arcane Background (Chi Mastery).

Answer (score 1):

### The edge is replaced by the one in the *Deadlands* book.

It is common for savage worlds books to replace edges found in the core rulebook. Normally, some kind of information is given about why the edge changed. Or, when an edge is banned, it says so and leaves a small note explaining the reason.

In the *Deadlands Reloaded* book, that didn't happen regarding the **Martial Arts** edge, but you can see how *martial artists* in the setting are completely different from the ones in the core rules. Starting on page 92, there is a long list of changes (for better) for martial artist characters, and among those, there is a new edge called **Superior Kung-fu**, which grants even more advantages to martial artists and the ability to pick a fighting style. The **Eagle Claw Style** option says:

> **Eagle Claw**: This is a fast, vicious style where you hold your hands like claws and tear away at some poor sodbuster’s pressure points.
>
> Your Fighting attacks now inflict **Str+d4 damage** with AP 2.

While the **Tan Tui Style** says:

> **Tan Tui**: This style relies predominantly on kicks, and we don’t mean can-can style. Up in Shan Fan, this one’s very popular with spectators at various martial arts tournaments. Your hombre’s **kicks cause Str+d6 damage**. He can use his powerful legs to rise from Prone at no movement cost.

So, to gain that extra damage that is found on the core rulebook, a martial artist has to pick the correct style as his martial arts.

Comment: So to go beyond Strength for damage in deadlands you have to purchase two edges, but the second edge (eagle claw) adds back the original d4  and AP2?  I had been assuming the styles added just the AP2 or Die upgrade/prone features, but this is my first Deadlands game so I have nothing to base that assumption on.

Comment: @Jtest wait for a few days before accepting the answer as correct, so we can wait for more (and probably) better answers to come up.